# How to catch a log from console from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, console.log

I want to get the logs in console which are from my iFrame tag and display it inside another element.

```
window.console = {
    log: function(str){
        let node = document.createElement("li");
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
        document.getElementById("consoleMsgHere").appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

This code is able to get common consoles from the document but is not able to catch a log from the iframe tag.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably `window.top.document.getElementById("consoleMsgHere").appendChild(node)` would be required, else the `iframe` relates on its own `document`. Depending on domain restrictions this *might* not be possible.

Comment: seems like there is no possible way for it :(

Comment: If you have control of both sites in question you can use `postMessage()` to forward it, regardless of the domain.

Comment: Yes! I have control over both sides. I am actually make a code editor where users can write JavaScript and that shows inside the iframe.

Can you explain a little more briefly how can I fix my issue with `postMessage()`?

Comment: In that case you can set it up using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Change your `log()` to `postMessage()` to `window.top` and add a `receiveMessage` on the top window. Like that it will fetch both messages from the top and the sub (=iframe) sites.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
If I replace `console.log('message')` with `window.parent.postMessage("message", "*")`, I am able to catch the log by the `receiveMessage()` function.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Tried to make a demo, yet iframes are not very welcome in snippets sadly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic example. Alas I can not provide a snippet due to iframe restrictions. Therefore this is more of a *copy-pate-to-dekstop* example.

Basically I changed your `log()` to `window.top.postMessage()` and on the `window.top` we add a listener on `message` which handles the incoming messages. Consult the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for further details.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //REM: Overwriting console.log()
            window.console = {
                log: function(str){
                    //REM: Forward the string to the top window.
                    //REM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
                    window.top.postMessage(str, '*');
                }
            };

            //REM: Listening to messages
            window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
                //REM: Just appending it to the body.. lazy
                document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(event.data))
            }, false);

            //REM: Just required for the demo..
            window.onload = function(){
                if(window.top !== window.self){
                    //REM: Changing the color of the body to distinguish iframe and not iframe
                    document.body.style.background = 'limegreen'
                }
                else{
                    //REM: Adding itself as an iframe to demostrate the logic while being lazy
                    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).src = window.location.href
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = 'text' value = 'test' onchange = 'console.log(this.value)' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `n` is a user's long and unpredictable code, then is there any way to change all `console.log("message")` to `window.top.postMessage("message", '*');` ??

btw I am using ace.

Comment: You can see the way in your post and my example. We just overwrite the `window.console.log()`. What is *ace*? :-)

Comment: why have you put **;** before window in your code ( before event listeners ) ??

Comment: A habbit while dealing with external script bundlers and/or script minifiers, since you never know whether they end with `; `. You can totally ignore it here.

Comment: You can see my `onchange` doing a `console.log()` which gets overwritten to `postMessage()` at the start.  So you only have to overwrite the function once (on every page) like in your original example.